# How to use group-by and get other rows results

Tags: sql, database, group-by

Question: if this is my data:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
===================
www.com,0,dangerous,reason A
www.com,1,dangerous 2,reason B
```

I want the a single result where column 2 value is max, so I will use in my select the  Max(col2) function - but how can I get those corresponding col3 and col4 row ?

```
select 
    col1, max(col2), col3, col4
group by 
    col1
```

and ???

Thanks
Idan

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` and limit to one row.  The ANSI-standard syntax is:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.col2 desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Not all databases support the `fetch first` clause, so you might have to use `select top 1`, `limit`, or some other construct.

Comment: thanks but would not it limit all my results to one ? I need it to continue and run on all rows ?

Comment: @idadolev . . . What do you mean?  Your question is explicitly:  "I want the a single result where column 2 value is max".  If you have another question, you should ask another (unambiguous) question, with sample data, desired results, and the proper database tag.

Comment: col1,col2,col3,col4
===================
www.com,0,dangerous,reason A
www.com,1,dangerous 2,reason B
www1.com,0,dangerous 3,reason c
www1.con,1,dangerous 4,reason c

I wish to get one result per col1 with the highest dangerous num and reason

Answer (score 0):

You can use where in select statement 
Like

```
Select * from table name where col2=max(col2)
```

You can get max column entire row with single value

If the column col2 which contain same value like 1,1,2,2 at this time above query return the 2 rows. At that time if you want single row you want to use this

```
Select * from table name where col2=max(col2) fetch first 1 row only
```

Might be this helpful